# Is it possible to work around the need to have a sever level permission with ownership chaining or the sort?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions

I want to give everyone access to a very limited portion of the dynamic management views. That is, I want everyone in my database to be able to select from this view:

```
create view dbo.KnowYourself
as
select
  net_transport,
  protocol_type,
  client_net_address
from
  sys.dm_exec_connections   -- requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission
where
  session_id = @@SPID;
```

`dm_exec_connections` is a management view in the `master` database.

I make sure that `dbo.KnowYourself` belongs to `sa` and that `sa` maps to the same user in my database and in `master`. I make sure both `master` and my database have `DB_CHAINING ON`, and are trustworthy just in case, even though it should not matter.

Still, no one can select from the view because they lack the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission.

I am aware of two workarounds:

- Turn the view into a multi-step table-valued function and assign `with execute as owner` to it.

  This does not work for me because certain queries significantly drop in performance when they have to call a multistep or scalar function instead of an inline function or a view (three seconds vs two hours).
- Give all my users `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission, create them all in the `master` database and [assign them `DENY` permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2016#required-permissions) on all dynamic management views except the one I need.

  That may work, but concerns me as a management burden going forward (I will have to do that for each new user, and I will have to keep denying new management views as they appear in next versions of SQL Server).

Is there a better way to give any user ability to select from this view?

Comment: Have you considered an stored procedure [executed as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @McNets That is even worse than a multi-step table-valued function because it cannot be called from queries at all.

Comment: `TRUSTWORTHY` isn't a requirement for `DB_CHAINING`. It's only needed when a module (e.g. stored proc) contains `EXECUTE AS <user>` and the security context must be extended to other databases. Module signing is a better solution for that use case. Server-level permissions like `VIEW SERVER STATE` are granted to logins, not users, so you don't need to create a user in master. Why use a mult-statement TVF when the view can be encapsulated in an in-line TVF?

Comment: @DanGuzman Multi-step TVF is because `with execute as` cannot be applied to an inline TVF. I do need to create users in `master` because with the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission they have full access to all management views and to stop that, I need to apply database-level `DENY` permissions to all views they should not see, [like it is explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-2017).